# How much of a performance boost I can get by using nginx on top of Django CMS?

Tags: django, apache, nginx, hosting

The static page content comes from Django CMS which makes it dynamic , How is using nginx in such a scenario beneficial ?

Answer (score 0):

It is generally considered a best practice to have *"static"* content served by a traditional web server such as Nginx or Apache. By static content, I am referring to things like CSS, JavaScript, and Images. Since these files often don't require modification between requests, there is little sense in having Django serve them. And Nginx/Apache can be serving these files to the client's browser concurrently.

However, your dynamic content served by Django needs to be rendered within the context of one or more Django templates. Not to mention, content such as blog posts needs to be retrieved from the database. Fortunately, Django has a robust [caching system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/) that you can use to cache the rendered HTML output and decrease server load and response times.

How much of a performance boost you gain really depends on the situation. I can tell you from experience that caching a complex response has reduced the response time from **300ms** down to **30ms** in one scenario.

EDIT: Adding a great article on [Scaling Django: Caching and Static Content.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scale-django-beyond-the-basics)

Comment: Thanks , can you point me to an example ,as to, how to bypass certain files types from Django and let some other server concurrently serve it ?

Comment: The recommended process is to have Django run with mod_wsgi in daemon mode. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode 
Personally,  I use the same Apache virtualhost to setup /static/ and /media/ folders to be served by Apache. There is a basic example in that same webpage: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Comment: This article is actually pretty good at explaining the various aspects of optimization for Django static files: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scale-django-beyond-the-basics